# How to get the computer time in php/laravel/js

Tags: localtime

I would like to see a solution for this that dont use timezone changing in php or JS, just a function that gets time computer time from windows directly. Windows has already a service that sincronize the computer to local time, so if you cen get this time should be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I got this in JS. It gets the computer time!! Not the server's.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
     var data = new Date();
     document.write(data.getHours() + ':' + data.getMinutes());
</script>
```